# Django Rest Framework / Angular - Serialization

Tags: django, angularjs, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have simple models like:

```
class Car(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    type = models.ForeignKey(CarTypes)


class CarTypes(models.Model):
    type_name = models.CharField()
```

and serializers:

```
class CarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Car
        depth = 1


class CarTypeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CarType
```

DRF send list of all Car Types to my frontend/angular app which looks like:

```
car_types = [
    {
        'id': 1,
        'type_name': 'Sedan'
    },
    {
        'id': 2,
        'type_name': 'Hatchback'
    }
]
```

I am using Car data in angular form i.e administrator would like to change data about car

```
<form>
 <input ng-model="car.name" type="text" />
 <select ng-model="car.type"
         ng-options="type.type_name for type in car_types track by type.id" 
         name="car_type">
 </select>
</form>
```

After submit this form angular send POST to django app which looks like:

```
    {
        'id': 1,
        'name': 'Audi',
        'type': {
            'id': 1,
            'type_name': 'Sedan'
        }
    }
```

**PROBLEM**

This is case when i am updating Car data.
If i change car type in selectbox my DRF serializer will change name from Sedan to i.e Hatchback instead of ascribe whole object. So Car Type Sedan will be destroyed and replaced.
New Car types will looks like:

```
car_types = [
    {
        'id': 1,
        'type_name': 'Hatchback'
    },
    {
        'id': 2,
        'type_name': 'Hatchback'
    }
]
```

(Angular send correct dict with id and name. DRF accessing only name instead of id and name to car.type)

**QUESTIONS**

1. How should I serialize and deserialize data with FK ? As a PrimaryKey then in angular connect those Primary Keys with names ? I like using depth options because i received whole dict
2. Maybe there is function in DRF to change data before validation which allow me to change received DICT to PK ?

Comment: In fact you may need to add new types when the type does not exist. Then you'll have to select among existing types to change the type of a car.

Comment: all types in selectbox exists. type_name is replaced because my serializer Car has instance which means update instead of create:
car_serializer = CarSerializer(carInstance,                                                      data=request.DATA) ... and it could be because depth. If Car is updateing then DRF maybe think that CarType should be too

Comment: I think you will need some backend logic to manage this. Like an update view which will look up at the CarType name. If it already exists, change the CarType of the Car or create a new one if unknown (or throw an error).